# How to utilize following ECM technologies - comparison

Tags: java, content-management-system, solr, jackrabbit, apache-tika

I have a theoretical question. I have tons of documents of various formats (ODS, MS office, pdf, html) and I'd like to implement ECM system that is not a document management system but rather system that persists metadata and data of documents (of variety of languages) in a unified manner (xhtml) into filesystem and database (only metadata) and that does data processing (indexing, searching).

What technologies would you use and how would you proceed ? These are my options:

Using only Apache Tika - parsing these document and extract metadata and data into xhtml format and then use Lucene or Solr for indexing and fulltext (big disadvantage is database persistence - metadata varies a lot)

Using only Apache Solr with Tika [parsers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRichDocuments) - I don't have experience with it. Does it have a support for database integration like Apache Nutch ?

Then there is Apache UIMA project - very hard to find out what is going on under the hood

Using some CMS that is already using Apache Tika (alfresco, apache jackrabbit) - But I don't have much experience with them. Anyway I'm sure that they have already taken care of problems like (doc vs. docx  or different metadata types ) that Apache Tika itself doesn't take care of.

I could also use native XML database like eXist db after I get the xhtml format from Apache Tika, but I'm not sure that it is a good choice because the structure of these document is rather flat. XML database is for more hierarchical document persistence.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an "out of the box" solution, you could consider using an integration framework like Camel and establish a camel route for extracting entities from files (using tika) and migrate them on to your database through jdbc. Otherwise, it sounds like a typical data mining task starting with raw source data and ending with extracted entities.